# is there any better way to add separate single line to multiple line in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a function in PHP to separate single line string to multiple line string.  My function is given below'

```
function addNewlines($content = null, $split_as = 25, $seprater = PHP_EOL) {
    $result = '';
    while ($content != null) {
      $result .= substr($content, 0, $split_as) . $seprater;
      $content = substr($content, $split_as);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I am calling this fucntion from an  another  function which used to export database data to excel,

```
 $detail[$value]= $this->addNewlines($detail[$value]);//call function to split
```

which may call these function for all rows fetched from DB.
You can see addNewlines function may take 10 iterations for a string contains 250 characters. is there any better way to reduce the number of iterations or optimize this function. I mean using regex or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the build in functions `str_split` to split the line in chuncks and `implode` to glue the resulting array with `PHP_EOL`.

```
$result = implode ( PHP_EOL , str_split( $string , 25 ) );
```

Comment: PHP_EOL is not recommended unless you want it's side effects (platform-dependent end-of-line string). Usually when dealing with target file formats (like in this case "Excel"), that format has some distinct requirements regarding line breaks, which should be added regardless of the platform PHP is running. So better use `"\n"` for single LF (Linux-style newline), or `"\r\n"` for CR-LF (Windows-style newline).